# Sort Flink DataSet based on multiple KeySelectors

Tags: apache-flink, flink-batch

I want to sort a POJO DataSet based on multiple values with therefore Multiple KeySelector Functions:

```
    DataSet<PoJo> data = input
            .sortPartition(new KeySelector<PoJo, Integer>() { 
                 public Integer getKey(PoJo element) { return someKeyFromPojo(element); }}, Order.Descending)
            .sortPartition(new KeySelector<PoJo, Integer>() { 
                 public Integer getKey(PoJo element) { return anotherKeyFromPojo(element); }}, Order.Ascending);
```

This yields an "KeySelector cannot be chained" error. According to the Flink Documentation it should be possible to chain sortPartition Functions.

Is there a way to solve this without using Field expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain `sortPartition` calls if and only if you use `sortPartition(int field, Order order)` or `sortPartition(String field, Order order)`. `sortPartition(KeySelector<T, K> keyExtractor, Order order)` does not allow chaining.

If you must compute the key, your `KeySelector` can return whatever you like, so long as it is hashable and comparable. E.g., a Tuple such as `(someKey, anotherKey)`.

Comment: But doesnt this limit my possibilities to sort in different orders ?

Comment: Assuming you return some class `MyKey` from your `PoJo` which has two fields, then you can define the comparator for `MyKey` such that it sorts descending (so inverse order) for the first field, and if that first field is equal, then sort ascending for the second field.